# Clipping axes with patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, clipping

I have some trouble understanding how to clip an axes with a patch. I would like to have the blue rectangle be in the background of the axes. But my clipping call does nothing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:.1, -1:1:.1]
Z = X+Y

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.contourf(X, Y, Z)

frame = patches.Rectangle(
        (-.1,-.1), 1.2, 1.2, transform=ax1.transAxes, alpha=.5, fc='b', fill=True, linewidth=3, color='k'
    )
ax1.set_clip_path(frame) # has no effect
fig.patches.append(frame)

fig.show()
```

[image]

How do I need to set this up correctly? The documentation is very lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to provide the `zorder` to put it into the background. Specifically, `zorder=0` in the present case for your `Rectangle` patch.

Think of `zorder` as the parameter which decides what is stacked on top of what. `zorder=0` would simply send the patch lowest in the stack which means the back most layer of the plot.

```
frame = patches.Rectangle(
        (-.1,-.1), 1.2, 1.2, transform=ax1.transAxes, alpha=.5, fc='b', fill=True, linewidth=3, color='k'
    , zorder=0) # <--- zorder specified here
ax1.set_clip_path(frame) # has no effect
fig.patches.append(frame)
```

[image]

Comment: @lotolmencre: I am frankly speaking unaware of `set_clip_path` so I cannot unfortunately answer this question. But now you mentioned it, I will read about it. The documentation is hardly existing

Comment: @lotolmencre: By the way, why do you expect the patch to be applied behind the plot? In principle, it's use is mainly to clip a plot region. You are using it uniquely to have a colored background which can also be achieved using frame color.

Comment: This was a degenerate example. I want the box to frame multiple axes objects.